# Make an annotation based on users location in an IBaction

Tags: iphone, objective-c, dictionary, mapkit, xcode4.5

I want to do an annotation on the user's currently location when he presses a button, I tried with core location, but it is uncompatible.

this is an example:

```
-(IBAction)anotation:(sender){


    CLLocationCoordinate2d *coor;

    MKUserlocation *ul;

    coor.latitude = **ul.location.latitude** //or something like that;

    ...
    ...


}
```

Can you help me?

Comment: "I tried with core location, but it is uncompatible." what do you mean by this? You can perfectly do this, I made it a lot of times. What's the exact problem that you met?

Comment: If you want to show the _default blue dot_, just do `mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;` (you're not supposed to create the MKUserLocation annotation explicitly).

Comment: How about reading [Location Awareness Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/Introduction/Introduction.html)?

Answer (score 0):

Try this Action zoomToCurrentLocation for your button click. getGotFix checks a flag set by this callback

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation
```

Here is the IBAction code (I am sure there are duplicates on SO)

```
- (IBAction)zoomToCurrentLocation:(id)sender 
{

MKCoordinateRegion region;

if ([utils getGotFix] == YES)
{
    region.center = self.mapView.userLocation.coordinate; 

    MKCoordinateSpan span; 
    span.latitudeDelta  = 2; // Change these values to change the zoom 1 degree = 69 miles
    span.longitudeDelta = 2; 
    region.span = span;

    MKCoordinateRegion viewRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(region.center, 2*METERS_PER_MILE, 2*METERS_PER_MILE);
    MKCoordinateRegion adjustedRegion = [mapView regionThatFits:viewRegion]; 
    [mapView setRegion:adjustedRegion animated:YES];  
}
else 
{   // We dont yet have a user location fix so inform user
    UIAlertView * timeoutAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"No location fix" message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [timeoutAlert show];
}
```

}